# how select image from gallary and pass it to another activity,

Tags: android, android-studio

I am making a birthday wisher app, everthing works fine but I want that user can select image from gallary and it passes to 2nd activity, when timer is finised, I used ticker coundown in this.

My MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    CircularView circularViewWithTimer;
    EditText entertime;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getWindow().setFlags(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS
        );

        entertime = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Txt_time);

        circularViewWithTimer = findViewById(R.id.circular_view);

        CircularView.OptionsBuilder builderWithTimer =
                new CircularView.OptionsBuilder()
                        .shouldDisplayText(true)
                        .setCounterInSeconds(15)
                        .setCircularViewCallback(new CircularViewCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onTimerFinish() {
                               String name = entertime.getText().toString();
                                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Bday_page.class);
                               i.putExtra("text", name);
                                startActivity(i);
                                finish();
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onTimerCancelled() {

                                // Will be called if stopTimer is called
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "CircularCallback: Timer Cancelled ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                            }
                        });

        circularViewWithTimer.setOptions(builderWithTimer);
    }

    public void btn_pause(View view) {
        circularViewWithTimer.pauseTimer();
    }

    public void btn_start(View view) {
        MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;

        if(entertime.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Enter name of bday boy", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else {
            circularViewWithTimer.startTimer();

            mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.count);
            mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            mMediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
            mMediaPlayer.start();
        }
    }

    public void btn_resume(View view) {
        circularViewWithTimer.resumeTimer();
    }
}
```

My 2nd Activity

```
public class Bday_page extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView nameuser;
    MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_bday_page);
       nameuser = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_imagename);

        getWindow().setFlags(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS
        );

        mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.happybady);
        mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        mMediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
        mMediaPlayer.start();

        Intent i = getIntent();
        nameuser.setText(i.getStringExtra("text"));


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all you have to request the storage permission in the manifest

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

after that in your MainActivity make your onTimerFinish methods like these

```
@Override
                    public void onTimerFinish() {
  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    intent.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(intent,1777);
}
```

now you requsted the image from Galary then add onActivityResult method to your main activity to receive the image

```
 @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
if ( resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST) {
 Uri uri = data.getData();
            Cursor cursor;
String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
                    cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri,
                            filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                    cursor.moveToFirst();

                    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                    picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                    cursor.close();
String name = entertime.getText().toString();
                        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Bday_page.class);
                       i.putExtra("text", name);
                       i.putExtra("imagePath",picturePath )
                        startActivity(i);
                        finish();
}}}
```

now you get the path of selected image and send it to the next activity
and in your 2nd Activity receive the image like these

```
Intent i = getIntent();
nameuser.setText(i.getStringExtra("text"));
String imagePath = i.getStringExtra("imagePath") //add these
```

now you have the image Path in the new activity you can do what you want to do with it

Comment: but i want  that user select the image through a button ,and start the the countdown timer , when countdown finishes , Bday_page Activity is shown with image seleted from the gallary and text from edittext,,,,please help me

Comment: you want him to click a button then select an image after that the count start to redirect him to the next activity?

Comment: yes yes yes, when countdown finshes  he redirect to next activity, and in next activity he see the selected image  by the user,

Comment: and i also have another button to start the count start, i simply want that user select the image from select image button and enter the name in edit text and press the start button on pressing start button count down start , as count downdown finishes, the go second activity where he found the selected image and name ,  hope you get what i want to do

Comment: please go through the link what i have tried to do and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63872400/image-is-not-showing-in-next-activity

Comment: OK i will check that and try to help you please accept these answer if it help you to know how to  select image from gallery and pass it to another activity,